# Saving registration info from anonymous users

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to have a form on my site where anonymous users can register their interest in 'soon to be released' products.

I've had a look at the Contact module, however, I would prefer the registrations to be saved in the database, not emailed to me. Also, I would like to be able to add custom fields/check-boxes so the users can tick which products they want to hear about.

Is there an existing module that provides this functionality, or are there modules that would make it easy to build this kind of form?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I've just discovered the webform module (http://drupal.org/project/webform). This will possibly do what I'm looking for, although any other suggestions are welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Webform module](https://drupal.org/project/webform) will do just what you're looking for, as Adnan suggests in the comments above. Webform is more often used to send email, but the emails are optional and it does record form submissions in the database. It also provides reports, to get the information back out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Actually sounds like you're looking for more something like [SimpleNews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) or [Mailing list](http://drupal.org/project/mailing_list) and not Webform.